# Using custom formula with Matheval in C#

Tags: c#, string, function, evaluate

```
private double xpy(double x, double y)
{
    return x + y;
}

...
org.matheval.Expression exp = new org.matheval.Expression();            
exp.SetFomular("2 * xpy(a, b)");  
exp.Bind("a", 1.2);
exp.Bind("b", 0.8);
var result = (double)exp.Eval();
...
```

The Matheval homepage lists "Custom functions and operators can be added at runtime" as a feature, but I can't find an example how to use a custom function (like xpy in the example) with it. How should the function be defined or specified?

My example leads to this exception:
System.Exception: 'Function XPY does not exist'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently supported by MathEval. There is an opened [issue](https://github.com/matheval/expression-evaluator-c-sharp/issues/7) and an [opened PR](https://github.com/matheval/expression-evaluator-c-sharp/pull/9) in the MathEval's repo for registering custom functions, but it's not merged.

Comment: Does anyone know of an alternative to Mathevel that offers this functionality?

Comment: @Cotty , I don't know which one is better but there are some: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43817154/evaluating-mathematical-expressions-with-custom-script-functions, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312225/best-free-c-sharp-math-parser-using-variables-user-defined-functions-custom-op 
. And e.g. custom functions in Jace : https://github.com/pieterderycke/Jace/blob/30053052cd4cb2fcabb49cd7bee1f20cbd5ee800/Jace.Tests/CalculationEngineTests.cs#L482 , custom functions in NCalc: https://github.com/ncalc/ncalc#functionalities